# Airflow EmrCreateJobFlowOperator `label is invalid: emr-6.8.0` Error On Latest EMR Version

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

[EMR released a new cluster version today](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-680-release.html)

But when I attempt to upgrade to the latest released EMR version using the [contributed](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.13/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/emr_create_job_flow_operator/index.html) EMR create job flow operator I'm hitting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1138, in _run_raw_task
    self._prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks(context, task)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1311, in _prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, task_copy)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1341, in _execute_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/plugins/operators/shippo_emr_operators.py", line 133, in execute
    return super().execute(context)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/operators/emr_create_job_flow.py", line 81, in execute
    response = emr.create_job_flow(job_flow_overrides)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/hooks/emr.py", line 88, in create_job_flow
    response = self.get_conn().run_job_flow(**config)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 676, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the RunJobFlow operation: The supplied release label is invalid: emr-6.8.0.
```

Looking at the EMR contribution code I don't see any hard coded values so I'm not sure why were hitting this error at this point. Has the label format changed and if so where can I find the exact string?

EDIT: The plot thickens. If I run `aws emr list-release-labels` I get

```
NextToken: AAIAAdZ_6MGjAhReZYcOrXICLpYU98iQO_ZB3kCK65qEWRH9MrJLdi_r-alVGb1AZlnFg0vsdxRUzdBLt-SyQ3TznUBM8Ncu7n94pJVQykbWe_TapxBi2WpUkcZfRAcxYgcg6TwejeaxGKcbysA89Jc9M3vIlVQetGgY1zQESS2Dq3P9vxvsOo3xxZoTqnmOVjs24Hy1hPM8zfzoUfH7MMomXkqhU5MHZ0cG3Aee5F51LtNS0_NBge399SiDYwhz1W2RB2tAjDc=
ReleaseLabels:
 - emr-6.7.0
 - emr-6.6.0
 - emr-6.5.0
 - emr-6.4.0
```

Which indicates that the release label has been updated in the docs but not actually released to the tooling?

Comment: It looks like AWS released this in some of the "early adopter" regions (e.g. us-east-1), but then subsequently yanked it.  The documentation seems also to have been updated to remove this version.

Comment: That's correct - we had to rollback and it will be deployed again in the coming days.

Comment: @dacort, thanks for the info/confirmation! It would've been useful to have had this communicated a little more openly since we had already started working on transitioning to the new version.  My suspicion is that we were not the only ones.

Comment: @MikeGM Heard - can definitely do a better job of communicating when something like this happens, especially since the docs had rolled out too and it's a pretty rare occurence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EMR release the new versions in a few regions first, probably you are trying to launch a cluster in a no available region yet.

Comment: This is in us-east-1 which is generally the first region features are released in.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: They yanked 6.8.0. I suggested my team to transition but a few days later, they removed the info on 6.8.0 in every region. Though I cannot find any official source.